# SwiftUI - Image not ignoring safe area on devices(iphone 8 and 6)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

New to SwiftUI.
When showing the above screen i am not ignoring the safe area while using edgesIgnoringSafeArea.
Also when building on simulator it looks fine while on actual device it looks wrong as follow:[image]

[image]

what could be the issue?

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var appCoordinator: AppCorrdinator?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        self.window = window
        appCoordinator = AppCorrdinator(window: self.window!)
        appCoordinator?.start()
    }

final class AppCorrdinator: Coordinator {
    var window: UIWindow
    lazy private var mainCoordinator: MainCoordinator = {
        let navigationController = UINavigationController()
        window.rootViewController = navigationController
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
        return MainCoordinator(navigationController: navigationController)
    }()
    
    init(window: UIWindow) {
        self.window = window
    }
    
    func start() {
        mainCoordinator.start()
    }
}

final class MainCoordinator: Coordinator {
    let navigationController: UINavigationController
    
    init(navigationController: UINavigationController) {
        self.navigationController = navigationController
    }
    
    func start() {
        let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: TestView(viewModel: ViewModel()))
        navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
        
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.blue , .white]),
                           startPoint: .topLeading,
                           endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                Image("Test").resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .overlay(
                        Button(action: {
                        print(">> Trash Tapped")
                    }) {
                        Image("iconCloseBlack")
                    },
                        alignment: .center
                    )
                    .padding(.bottom, 40)
                    
                Text("dfsfdf")
            }
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height, alignment: .top)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView(viewModel: ViewModel())
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine here. Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15 / iPhone 8. Would you attach used image?

Comment: It's actually because of the Navigation Bar. It's not `Truly` ignoring the safe area on your device. Based on the SS, looking at the radial blur on the top right. Notice it's not as big on the Simulator, because it's clipped behind. The code you have provided is not enough to fully reproduce.

Comment: Working fine here too. Problem might be like what @xTwisteDx said

Comment: @ironRoei can I ask what you're attempting to accomplish? I'm looking at your views, and they look just weird.

Comment: @xTwisteDx add additional code that is not UI related ...

Comment: @Asperi You think it is the image?

Comment: Well, taking into account update and that you install it via UIKit, then no - it's not an image.

Comment: @Asperi any other ideas ?